# Install dotnet sdk latest release of a specific major Version

Tags: .net, powershell, chocolatey

I have a task of installing latest 6.x.x version of dotnet-sdk on powershell. We are currently using chocolatey to install the pinned sdk version but chocolatey doesnt suppport wildcards.

Current Code :

`choco install dotnet-sdk --version 6.0.302`

I have to install latest release from version 6.

I referred to this page https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0 but couldnt convert the installation to script.

Comment: That page links to the [.NET install scripts page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/scripts) along with the [install script documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website)

Comment: BTW the [.NET 6 SDK package](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/dotnet-6.0-sdk#files) is already the latest, you don't need to specify the version: `This is a metapackage, which installs the latest release of .NET 6.0 SDK across all feature updates.`. .NET 6 SDK isn't deployed through Chocolatey, what you find there is a *meta*package that downloads and installs the actual installation package

Comment: So I can see the latest .net sdk 8 version is "8.0.101". Is there any way in which it can keep fetching the latest version ?

Comment: Did you check the link package? It's specific to the major version so it *won't* install any 8.x version, it will install the latest 6 SDK. I repeat, .NET isn't deployed through Chocolatey. People created packages that load specific versions and those people ensured there are packages that download specific major versions. When new versions come out, the maintainers update their choco packages as well `choco install dotnet-6.0-sdk` will always install the latest version - according to the maintainer

Comment: Why do you want this anyway? Create a build server pipeline? In that case wouldn't it be better to use Docker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to use Chocolatey, install the dotnet-6.0-sdk package without a version :

```
choco install dotnet-6.0-sdk
```

As the docs explain:

> This is a metapackage, which installs the latest release of .NET 6.0 SDK across all feature updates.

.NET SDK isn't deployed through Chocolatey. What you find there is a *meta*package that downloads and installs the actual installation package. The maintainers of those packages ensured there's both an overall package, `dotnet-sdk` and packages specific to major versions like `dotnet-6.0-sdk`. Every time a new SDK is released, the maintainers update the packages.

Another option is to download and use the official .NET installation scripts. There's always a link in the .NET SDK download page, that links to the [script download page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/scripts) and the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website)
If you *don't* need Chocolatey, you can use the Powershell .NET installation scripts found in the .NET download page.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Also appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Just to offer an alternative to using Chocolatey for the installation.

You can also install .NET SDKs via [`winget.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/), the [Windows Package Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/) CLI:

```
# Installs the latest .NET 6 SDK.
# Run From an ELEVATED session.
winget install Microsoft.DotNet.SDK.6 -h
```

- The `-h` (`--silent`) option hides the installer's GUI.

  - Caveat: If you run the command *without* elevation (not from a session started with `Run As Administrator`), you'll still get *one* GUI element, namely the UAC dialog for on-demand elevation. In combination with `-h` this dialog *doesn't pop up*; you need to activate it manually, via the task bar, in order to respond.
- To also hide `winget`'s own console output, append `*>$null`
- The above works analogously for other major .NET SDK releases, e.g. `Microsoft.DotNet.SDK.8`; to find them all, run:

  ```
  winget search Microsoft.DotNet.SDK.
  ```
- To later *remove* (uninstall) an SDK installed this way, use, e.g.:

  ```
  # Uninstall.
  # Run From an ELEVATED session.
  winget uninstall Microsoft.DotNet.SDK.6 -h
  ```